# Is there a way to set a scheduled task in an Android Application?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I'm working in an application that shows data from a MySQL database via PHP using WebServices with XAMPP and phpMyAdmin.

What I need to do now is a task or job that every 15 minutes or 'n' time set by the user configuration, makes a select to the database through a web service and return the data to show it as a notification in the phone.

Does Android have a way to do this kind of tasks or jobs?

I don't want to use `Thread`s, because as far as I know, they tend to make the app slow with time and it's also a bad practice.

Comment: You can try using ScheduledExecutorService .. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html or AlarmManager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889775/how-to-schedule-a-task-using-alarm-manager

Comment: You can schedule repeating alarm using AlarmManager and can perform tasks at the specified repeated intervals using PendingIntent .. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#tradeoffs